# How to Install .ipa file into my iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipa

Created .ipa file with Xcode 6, which I'm trying to install in my iPhone with iTunes. After saying it was "installing" nothing seems to have happened.

I waited for quite a long time, but it never progressed past that point. I followed all the steps correctly, so I don't know what could be happening.

Comment: What do you think the correct procedure is? What certificate did you use to sign your binary?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installation of an ipa file into iPhone device and not the programming question.

Comment: Used Development certificate for debug and Ad Hoc Certificate for release.

Answer (score 3):

This may be the case when there is some issue in profile. But anyway you can try by dragging .app file on itunes & then try to install on device by the procedure you are following.

Means dont create .ipa by xcode, just right click on the first entry from Organizer and then select 'show in finder', then again right click on xcode archive file & click on 'show package contents'. Then select .app file from Products -> applications. And drag & drop this .app file on itunes and then try to install.

May be this will help.